# Using os.system() inside a function

Tags: python

I have a nonpython program I am running with python using the os.system command, but I put this command inside a function. The program I want to run with os.system is supposed to give me an output file, and I need that output for processing, also I need that output to be actually written in the directory I am sending it to.

I wrote my function is the following general format

```
def myFunction(infile):
    os.system('myProgram '+infile+' '+outfileName)
    outfile = numpy.loadtxt(outfileName)
    return outfile
```

However, the output of myProgram (outfileName) isn't being written to my directory and numpy can't therefore load it. Is there a way to store globally outputs of programs I run using os.system when it's inside a function?

Comment: What is `outfileName`?  Is that variable in the scope of this function?

Comment: You may need to use an *absolute* path for `outfileName` to make sure it's where you want it to be.  Or, can you have `myProgram` output to STDOUT?

Comment: Even with absolute paths, it is not writing to my directory

Comment: Do you run this python program from the command line or double-click it? Do the input and output files have spaces in them? Did the program work... or does it error? I did `os.system('cp test test2')` and it worked fine. Can you substitute something like that and try it for sanity testing. Also, `print(repr('myProgram '+infile+' '+outfileName))` and post that here for us to see.  And of course... `retval = os.system('myProgram '+infile+' '+outfileName)` and test the program for a nonzero return code!

Comment: myProgram is able to run, as in addition to storing data into outfileName it also prints to screen additional data. The additional data I can see, but the data I want isn't writing to the directory I want it to be.

Comment: You may wish to look at replacing your `os.system()` call with [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)

Comment: `os.system` works generally (my test works) so its something specific in what you are doing. We don't have those specifics, so there isn't much we can do.

Comment: For all we know, your program adds a suffix to the output name. Or you are using an environment variable for the name. There are many things that could go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myProgram` is working correctly, this is likely happening because `myProgram` does not know the python path, so the file is simply being written somewhere else. Try using the full paths and see if that works.

Assuming `infile` and `outfileName` are relative paths in your current working directory, you could do:

```
def myFunction(infile):
    cmd  = 'myProgram ' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), infile)
    cmd += ' ' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), outfileName))
    os.system(cmd)
    outfile = numpy.loadtxt(outfileName)
    return outfile
```

Comment: What is "the python path" and how is it related to the problem? `os.system` uses the same current working directory as the program calling it. Joining with `getcwd()` is pointless, relative paths already work that way. Relative paths can be a problem if you are running the program by double-clicking it or running it as a daemon. But then, `getcwd()` would continue to be a problem.

Comment: Ah, good point. So then the culprit must be something in `myProgram`

Comment: Quite likely. He may be double-clicking from the desktop (so cwd is bad) or using spaces in the filenames. But I'm voting for something wrong with myprogram... and he really should be testing its return code.